# How to filter and copy a named range?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to export a filtered named range to a new workbook. My named range contains a variable amount of rows with a '0' in a specific column. I'd like to exclude those rows (which contain a '0' in column 'F') from my selection before exporting them to the new workbook.

Below is the code I'm using to copy the named range and paste it into a new workbook. So far so good, but I've got no clue on how to exclude the rows with a '0' in column 'F'; currently, the whole named range is pasted into a new workbook.

```
Dim MyFileName As String
Dim CurrentWB As Workbook, TempWB As Workbook

Set CurrentWB = ActiveWorkbook
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("my named range").Copy


Set TempWB = Application.Workbooks.Add(1)
With TempWB.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have already filtered your data and the zeros are hidden, change the following line:

```
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("my named range").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
```

If you have not filtered, then use `AutoFilter`

```
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("my named range").AutoFilter Field:=(number of field), Criteria1:="<>0"
```

followed by the line above...

Comment: You saved the day Darrel! Thank you so much!